# Table and inputs - Power Apps

Tags: powerapps-canvas

How can I display a table with some input felds and after that to be able to save it all in a SharePoint List. That means Name, ID, Date, Departement, Col.1, Col.2... are columns in the same list.
Which approach should I choose?
Here is what I want to do :
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: @SIE_Vict0ria I could not find a satisfying solution, that's why I changed my approach. I will only display a form. It will reset and display a new form after every submit. The combination between table and input seems to be complicate to build in the power apps.  And I use this approach too from [RezaDorrani] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI6SHGQ9ATg)

Answer (score 0):

@SIE_Vict0ria I could not find a satisfying solution, that's why I changed my approach. I will only display a form. It will reset and display a new form after every submit. The combination between table and input seems to be complicate to build in the power apps. And I use this approach too from [RezaDorrani] (youtube.com/watch?v=wI6SHGQ9ATg)

Comment: This should be a comment since it's not an actual answer.